# Changing the value of a single number in a string to zero

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

After a user enters a string of digits, the Python code is to replace the 5 with a 0, but I have not been able to overcome errors in syntax. I tried reading [the reference on if statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if) but was unable to identify the issue. Thank you.

```
string = input('Enter a string of digits: ')
length_of_string = len(string)
counter = 0
while (counter <= length_of_string):
    {
       if string[counter] == '5':
           string[counter] = '0'
           counter = counter + 1
       else:
           counter = counter + 1
           continue
    }
```

```
File "<ipython-input-37-154bb43ba751>", line 15
    if string[counter] == '5':
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Python does not use brackets (`{}`) for code blocks. Just indent it with 4 spaces.

Comment: ```>>> from __future__ import braces
SyntaxError: not a chance```

Comment: In Python, a string is immutable. You cannot overwrite the values of immutable objects.
`string[counter] = '0'` will raise `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`. Use `replace()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to replace those '0' with '5' ?
Is this what you are looking for?

```
string = input('Enter a string of digits: ')
replaced_string = string.replace('5', '0')
print(replaced_string)
```

Here is another solution for you with for loop and if statements:

```
string = input('Enter a string of digits: ')
replaced_string = ""
for char in string:
    if char == "5":
        replaced_string += "0"
    else:
        replaced_string += char
print(replaced_string)
```

Comment: Thank you MisterNox, this is tremendously helpful.